# Cross compiling for raspberryPi -- including libraries from synchronized filesystem

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile simple project on my PC to get working on RaspberryPi. I found some tutorials on web and made cmake file. Basic cmake file work on rpi side, but cross compile additional file have some problems. Makefiles are generated properly, but invoking `make` throws out that it can't find 
`wiringPi.h` library, which ofc I am using. I have synchronized /lib and /usr from rpi to my pc.

Here is my cmake for cross compilation.

```
#info
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
# specify the cross compilers
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER
/home/voodoo16/raspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
/home/voodoo16/raspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
# where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/voodoo16/raspberryPi/fs)
# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Of course I invoke cmake creation via:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=crossCompile.cmake .
```

Files exist in fs folder. Here is output of find:

```
voodoo16@tesla:[~/raspberryPi/fs]$ find -name *wiringPi*
./usr/local/include/wiringPiSPI.h
./usr/local/include/wiringPi.h
./usr/local/include/wiringPiI2C.h
./usr/local/lib/libwiringPi.so
./usr/local/lib/libwiringPi.so.2.32
./usr/local/lib/libwiringPiDev.so
./usr/local/lib/libwiringPiDev.so.2.32
./usr/lib/libwiringPi.so
./usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so
```

I suppose that I'm missing some cmake command which allows to see libraries from rpi filesystem not via pc system using standard `#include <lib.h>`.

Best regards,
voodoo16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set CMake variable [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) for hint compiler about cross compilation:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/home/voodoo16/raspberryPi/fs")
```

---

CMake variables `CMAKE_FIND_*` affects only on CMake `find_*` commands, they don't directly hint the compiler. From the other side, `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable hints for `find_*` commands too.

Comment: That works works, but have another problem. Now it cannot see `<sys/cdefs.h>`. May it be related to cmake problem or to compiler itself?

Comment: Are you sure you have this header file under sysroot?

Comment: `voodoo16@tesla:[~/raspberryPi/fs]$ find . -name *cdefs.h*
./usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/cdefs.h
`

Comment: Probably, you need to include this directory manually: `include_directories("/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf")`.

Comment: This do not help much. Set `include_directories("/home/voodoo16/raspberryPi/fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf")`. Solves missing `<sys/cdefs.h>`. Then it complains about missing `<gnu/stubs-soft.h>` (the hell??). Changed it in hard way to always read `<gnu/stubs-hard.h>`. And in a final, it complains about missing `-lwiringPi`. So perhaps it still don't see fs or it is fault of compilator.

Comment: I don't know about `gnu/stubs*`, but as concerned to missed `-lwiringPI` it is **CMakeLists.txt** who should properly find this library (via `find_library` or `find_package`) and use it in `target_link_libraries` call. Your toolchain needn't to bother about supporting direct `-lwiringPL`.